# How to get unique record by its sequence no

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table which contains the data like:

```
Name        Code    Sequence    AutoIncrementId
------------------------------------------------
Prashant    14323     1             11
Prashant    14323     1             12
Prashant    14323     1             13
Prashant    14323     1             14
Nishant     11323     2             11
Nishant     11323     2             12
Nishant     11323     2             13
Nishant     11323     2             14
Sushant     13223     3             11
Sushant     13223     3             12
Sushant     13223     3             13
Sushant     13223     3             14
Jishant     14223     4             11
Jishant     14223     4             12
Jishant     14223     4             13
Jishant     14223     4             14
```

Expected output is:

```
Name      Code      Sequence    AutoIncrementId
------------------------------------------------
Prashant  14323        1             11
Nishant   11323        2             12
Sushant   13223        3             13
Jishant   14223        4             14
```

Sample query to generate data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
Name NVARCHAR(200),
Code NVARCHAR(200),
Sequence NVARCHAR(200),
AutoIncrementId NVARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Prashant',14323,1,11)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Prashant',14323,1,12)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Prashant',14323,1,13)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Prashant',14323,1,14)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Nishant',11323,2,11)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Nishant',11323,2,12)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Nishant',11323,2,13)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Nishant',11323,2,14)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Sushant',13223,3,11)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Sushant',13223,3,12)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Sushant',13223,3,13)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Sushant',13223,3,14)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Jishant',14223,4,11)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Jishant',14223,4,12)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Jishant',14223,4,13)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Jishant',14223,4,14)
```

The Query that I have tried:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AutoIncrementId,Sequence) as RN,* 
FROM #temp ORDER BY RN
```

Comment: Why store all those duplicate rows?

Comment: @jarlh: The actual query is quite big and by using JOIN managed to get the data as like this

Comment: I see. Then do `SELECT DISTINCT`, as already suggested below.

Comment: @jarlh: Have updated my question please have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use subquery and use a little bit trick here

```
   select Name,code,Sequence,AutoIncrementId from
   (
   SELECT *, dense_rank() OVER(partition by Name,code,Sequence ORDER BY  AutoIncrementId) as RN

    FROM #temp 
    ) t  where rn-Sequence=0
    order by Sequence
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=13ed50ab73113a0922d253d5edda5914)

```
    Name        code    Sequence    AutoIncrementId
   Prashant     14323   1           11
   Nishant      11323   2           12
   Sushant      13223   3           13
   Jishant      14223   4           14
```

Comment: Sorry, unable to provide proper data. Have updated my question

Comment: The result is actually missing sequence 2 and 3 data!

Comment: Thanks for the answer it working for the AutoIncrementId - is `11,12,13,14` but for one case like `19,12,23,14`  not working!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale my answer is covered your current problem that you posted but the strange condition of accepting the answer :) you might post 2nd question about your 2nd issues

Comment: yup its working fine as provided data but if you can help then would be better for me! while this might be a case which need to handle!

Answer (score 3):

From your sample data,you can try to use `distinct`

```
SELECT distinct Namem,Code,Sequence,AutoIncrementId
FROM #temp
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unable to provide correct sample data, have updated my question have a look!

Comment: How does this get upvoted?  It should return a syntax error because `RN` is not in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the logic you want is.  Here is one method that returns the results you want:

```
select Name, Code, Sequence, 
       min(AutoIncrementId) + Sequence - 1 as AutoIncrementId
from #temp
group by Name, Code, Sequence;
```

The above assumes that the values that look like numbers are numbers.  But I see you have stored them as strings, so:

```
select Name, Code, Sequence, 
       convert(int, min(AutoIncrementId)) + convert(int, Sequence) - 1  as AutoIncrementId
from #temp
group by Name, Code, Sequence
order by sequence;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b5e39886382be4e4153cdd3e4cba502f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In case the `AutoIncrementId` is like `19,23,231,21` then?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale . . . This answers the question that you actually asked.  If you have a different question, please ask it as a *new* question, with proper explanation and sample data.  This question already has multiple answers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but in your table if any identity column is available then you can get the desired result using the below query also.

```
Select t.* from #temp t
inner join (
SELECT MIN(Id) as Id, Name, Code, Sequence
FROM   #temp
GROUP BY
       Name, Code, Sequence
)a on t.Id = a.Id
```

You can find the live demo [**here**](https://rextester.com/EFBXM6752).

Alternatively you have not identity column then You can apply logic such as create a new temp table which has identity column. Insert all records of original table in newly table and apply above query for that newly table which has the identity column.

You can find the live of this logic [**here**](https://rextester.com/LKZL1188).

Comment: Dont have identity column

Comment: @PrashantPimpale check my answer now